# Multi Go-Routine Loop Not Executing as Expected

Tags: go, goroutine

**EDIT to be more concise and clear

I'm fairly new to Go and absolutely new to GoRoutines, but I need to add a level of concurrency to my program I'm building.

What I'm looking to do with this is have both `go func` running concurrently, and they are, technically. They aren't running how I would expect them too however.

The top `go func` should run every five seconds looking for a new job and an open device to run the job on. If there are new jobs it checks for open devices. Assuming there are three new jobs and two open devices the `for _, device := range` loop should run twice assigning each job to a device. Five seconds later the loop would run again and see there is one job left to be run, and check if those devices are open to run the job. 
Meanwhile I'd expect the subSSH function to be continuously called.

What's actually happening is that the device loop only runs once every five seconds, so it only takes the first device and runs the code, then it waits five seconds and does the same thing with the second job, then the third job, never utilizing the second device or running that loop twice.

```
go func() {
    for {
        duration := 5 * time.Second
        for x := range time.Tick(duration) {//this loop runs every five seconds
            newJobs := checkForNew(jobcoll)
            if len(newJobs) != 0 {
                openPool := checkPoolDeviceStatus(poolcoll)
                for _, device := range openDevices {
                    //for each open device this loop should run once

                }
            }
        }
    }
}()

go func() {
    subSSH(subChannel, jobcoll, poolcoll)
}()
```

I've attempted adding wait groups in and adding a new wait for the number of new jobs, but this caused the device loop to never execute at all.

I think I'm missing something obvious here, and any assitance is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Try working on a [mcve], which will probably lead you to the issues. As it stands you haven't provided anything complete enough to now exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @JimB - I'll revamp my question to be a bit more generic and clear.

Comment: It's a bit hard to work out the problem without more of the code.
However one thing I noticed is that the outer for loop is unnec. asthe time.Tick() chan never gets closed, hence the "ticker" loop will never terminate.
 
If the innermost "device" loop is only executing once then len(openDevices) must be one.
To me it looks like you could step through the code to check this. If that's notpossible due to timing/concurrency interactions then log the value to try to understand what's happening.

Comment: As a tip, if you get stuck with concurrency and channels (which `time.Ticker` uses), use the Go Playground to help yourself get unstuck. Start with very simple use cases, like printing, so you can understand the concurrency patterns in Go. https://play.golang.org :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path with the ticker, but you have the variables in the wrong scopes. You also have a nested for loop, so go ahead and remove that.

You'll want something like this:

```golang
go func() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second) // setup outside the loop.
    for t := range ticker.C { // every time 5 seconds passes, this channel will fire.
        newJobs := checkForNew(jobcoll)
        if len(newJobs) != 0 {
            openPool := checkPoolDeviceStatus(poolcoll)
            for _, device := range openDevices {
                // the thing should occur.
            }
        }
    }
}()
```

That should do the trick. See: https://play.golang.org/p/zj6jdoduCcp

If you want a continuously executing goroutine, you'd want a continuous loop.

```golang
// only executes once and quits.
go func() { doTheThing() }()

// executes continuously after each execution exit.
go func() { for { doTheThing() } }()

// "background" function
go func() { doTheThingThatNeverExits() }()
```

A goroutine is designed to be a background process (oversimplication). A goroutine is just an ease-of-use wrapper for easy concurrency when calling functions.

Edit: Missed the last bit.

Comment: I think the "ticker" loop was OK. His question was why the "device" loop was only being executed once per outer loop.

You are right about the continuously executing go-routine, though.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start there - maybe i'm going about this wrong. I was looking at having two goroutines running, one that is always looking for changes in a database and then one that is looking for new jobs in the database. But I can't have both of them running continuously at the same time without using concurrency.

Comment: You can definitely do that, but the patterns are a bit different. Feel free to post more questions on the specifics of each and I'm sure you'll get the answers you need.